# How can I move my image vertically up?

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on my site. Just about the first thing there is. But it's pretty far down. I wanted to know how I can move it down. The website currently looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/29b9116903051e82640f63b7a1a14464.png

As you can see the logo is pretty far down and not near the top. The current code I have for the header (which has logo in it) is this:

```
<div id="header">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="" height="150" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" width="150" />
            <h1>Hey there! I'm Mario!</h1>
            <p> <h2>  AKA IridiumKills </h2> </p>
            <p>I'm a Coder, Gamer, DJ, Music Producer, and Designer!</a>
            <br />
            Now that you know a bit about me,why don't you scroll down to see some more?</p>
            <p> <span class="logo fa fa-arrow-down"> </span> </p>
        </div>
```

This seemed to fix my problem:

```
        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="" height="225" style="position:absolute;left:565px; top:40px;" width="225" />
            <h1>Hey there! I'm Mario!</h1>
            <p> <h2>  AKA IridiumKills </h2> </p>
            <p>I'm a Coder, Gamer, DJ, Music Producer, and Designer!</a>
            <br />
            Now that you know a bit about me,why don't you scroll down to see some more?</p>
            <p> <span class="logo fa fa-arrow-down"> </span> </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your header CSS?.

Comment: The HTML provided is not enough to re-create this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is more of a css problem, not just an HTML problem.

Your inline css (the *style=* stuff) is not working because you must add this:

```
style="position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;"
```

You might want to experiment with:

```
position:absolute;
```

vs

```
position:relative;
```

Important: As noted by Chris Coyer in the below referenced article, absolute positioning only works if your element is inside a div (any element) where the positioning has been set to `position:relative;` *(or `absolute` or `fixed` -- it only cannot be the default `position` setting, which is `position:static`)*  So, add this:

```
<div id="header" style="position:relative;">
```

See the below reference for more info.

Sources:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. I got it working with the first one. And after that I screwed around with the top and left till I got it right.

Comment: This seemed to work for me:   <!-- Header -->
   <div id="header">
    <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="" height="225" style="position:absolute;left:565px; top:40px;" width="225" />
    <h1>Hey there! I'm Mario!</h1>
    <p> <h2>  AKA IridiumKills </h2> </p>
    <p>I'm a Coder, Gamer, DJ, Music Producer, and Designer!</a>
    <br />
    Now that you know a bit about me,why don't you scroll down to see some more?</p>
    <p> <span class="logo fa fa-arrow-down"> </span> </p>
   </div>

Comment: Just a note: elements with `position: absolute` are positioned relative to their closest _positioned_ ancestor, not necessarily one with `position: relative`. For example you could have a `<div>` with `position: absolute` inside another `<div>` with `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

Use css to make

```
position:relative,
top: -10px;
```

Play with the top value till your needs are met

Inline it like this

```
style="position:relative; top:-10px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to the css of your image:

```
style: "position:relative;"
```

And modify the "top" property of your image to the location you need:

```
top:-10px; //for example
```